# Get table to aggregate in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am sure this is really easy to do but could some one tell me what I am doing wrong.

I have this table
[image]

When I add a new measure to do Target -Total Amount I get additional lines.

[image]

How do I remove these so it is aggregates?

reference for relationships
Salesperson is the same as Employee name
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is due to absence of some 'Sales person' in 'Sales Transaction'.[Saleseperons]
Change 'Sales Transaction'.[Saleseperons] to 'Sales person]'.Name in the matrix

Comment: I don't quite follow what you mean why would that change anything? I have tried that but it gives me the exact same output

Comment: Usually you get empty rows on "one" side if there is an absence on key values.  As I don't have your data I was not sure that the matrix was collected in a proper way. If exchange didn't influence then you can try  to change a link to  many-to-many or return a blank value with the measure for cases when a salesperson does not exists.  If you will not able to get blank value then add a data sample and I'll test the measure and advice it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your calculation in a `CALCULATE()`.